# Problems enabling a quit function in Python

Tags: python, quit

I'm pretty new to programming in general and I'm creating a small game for my younger sister...

I have a while loop in which I want to have an option to quit the game, but none of the quitting techniques I know of seem to work:

```
#main game:
while 1:
    input_event_1 = gui.buttonbox(
        msg = 'Hello, what would you like to do with your Potato Head?',
        title = 'Main Screen',
        choices = ('Check Stats', 'Feed', 'Exercise', 'Teach', 'Play', 'Go to Doctor', 'Change Favourite Thing', 'Get New Toy', 'Quit'))
    if input_event_1 == 'Check Stats':
        myPotatoHead.check_p_h_stats()
    if input_event_1 == 'Change Favourite Thing':
        myPotatoHead.change_favourite_thing()
    if input_quit == 'Quit':
        input_quit = gui.ynbox(
        msg = 'Are you sure you want to quit?',
        title = 'Confirm quit',
        choices = ('Quit', 'Cancel'))
        if input_event_quit == 'Quit':
            sys.exit(1)
```

grateful for any help.

Thanks

---

-----UPDATE-----

Thanks for the advice, but it's still not working:

here's the updated code:

```
#import the required modules:
import easygui as gui
import os


#-----CLASS-----------------------------------
#Class:
class PotatoHead:

#Atributes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = game_data
        self.first_name = self.data[0]
        self.last_name = self.data[1]
        self.gender = self.data[2]
        self.colour = self.data[3]
        self.fav_thing = self.data[4]
        self.toys = []
        self.toys.append(self.data[5])
        self.age = '0.0'
        self.hunger = '0.0'
        self.health = '0.0'
        self.fitness = '0.0'
        self.education = '0.0'
        self.happiness = '0.0'
        self.tiredness = '0.0'

    def check_p_h_stats(self):
        self.toys_string = str(self.toys)
        gui.msgbox(
            msg = '''
Name: ''' + self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name + '''
Gender: ''' + self.gender + '''
Colour: ''' + self.colour + '''
Favourite Thing: ''' + self.colour + '''
Toys:''' + self.toys_string + '''
Age: ''' + self.age + '''
Hunger: ''' + self.hunger + '''
Health: ''' + self.health + '''
Fitness: ''' + self.fitness + '''
Education: ''' + self.education + '''
Happiness: ''' + self.happiness + '''
Tiredness: ''' + self.tiredness + '''
''',
            title = 'Potato Head Stats',
            ok_button = 'Continue')

    def change_favourite_thing(self):
        new_fav_thing = gui.enterbox(
            msg = 'Enter the new favourite thing:',
            title = 'Change Favourite Thing',
            default = 'Type Here')
        self.fav_thing = new_fav_thing

#Methods:
#-----MAIN PROGRAM----------------------------
#set up game:
image = 'nest.gif'
game_choice = gui.ynbox(
    msg = """Would you like to start a new game,
or load a previously saved one?""",
    title = 'Start/Load Game',
    choices = ('New Game', 'Load Game'),
    image = image)
if game_choice == 1:
    fieldNames = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Gender', 'Colour', 'Favourite Thing',     'First Toy']
    new_p_head_data = []
    new_p_head_data = gui.multenterbox(
        msg = 'Fill in the starting information about your Potato Head:',
        title = 'New Game',
        fields = fieldNames,
        values = ('', '', 'Male/Female', 'Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, White, Black', '',     'Choose either Rattle, Pacifier, Teddy, Doll, or Soft Ball'))
    game_data = new_p_head_data
else:
    gui.msgbox('This function is not yet supported, please start again...')

myPotatoHead = PotatoHead()

#main game:
while 1:
    input_event_1 = gui.buttonbox(
        msg = 'Hello, what would you like to do with your Potato Head?',
        title = 'Main Screen',
        choices = ('Check Stats', 'Feed', 'Exercise', 'Teach', 'Play', 'Go to Doctor', 'Change Favourite Thing', 'Get New Toy', 'Quit'))
    if input_event_1 == 'Check Stats':
        myPotatoHead.check_p_h_stats()
    elif input_event_1 == 'Change Favourite Thing':
        myPotatoHead.change_favourite_thing()
    elif input_event_1 == 'Quit':
        input_quit = gui.ynbox(
            msg = 'Are you sure you want to quit?',
            title = 'Confirm quit',
            choices = ('Quit', 'Cancel'))
        if input_quit == 'Quit':
            sys.exit(1)
```

Am using PYthon 2.5.4 for Mac
and am using Easygui 0.83

Again, thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
if input_quit == 'Quit':
        input_quit = gui.ynbox(
        msg = 'Are you sure you want to quit?',
```

should be

```
if input_event_1 == 'Quit':
        input_quit = gui.ynbox(
        msg = 'Are you sure you want to quit?',
```

**Edit**: the reason it's still not working, according to the EasyGui tutorial, is that `ynbox` returns 0 or 1, rather than the string values of the choices.  So change to

```
    elif input_event_1 == 'Quit':
        input_quit = gui.ynbox(
            msg = 'Are you sure you want to quit?',
            title = 'Confirm quit',
            choices = ('Quit', 'Cancel'))
        if input_quit == 1:
            sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe your code

```
 if input_quit == 'Quit':
```

should be

```
 if input_event_1 == 'Quit':
```

just like your other checks?  I'm not familiar with that `buttonbox` thingy but the discrepancy between this one check and the others is immediately jarring and jumps to the eye...

**Edit**: ah, found it, it's from [easygui](http://www.ferg.org/easygui/tutorial.html#contents_item_9.1) (mentioning what frameworks you're using would be helpful!-) -- yep, it returns the string associated to the button, so the change I suggested above is definitely the key point.

Also, changing all the `if input_event_1` after the first one to `elif input_event_1` (since it can't be equal to more than one string, why keep checking once you've found the one string it **does** equal?-), while not strictly necessary, would be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It is more elegant this way:

```
she_wants_to_play = true
while she_wants_to_play:
    ask input
    if input == quit:
        she_wants_to_play = false
```

So you nicely quit the while loop, instead of hitting the system with a 10000 Ton weight.

Comment: While the loop structure you propose is perfectly elegant, there's nothing wrong with `sys.exit()`.  It's hardly an N-ton weight... it merely raises a nice `SystemExit` exception which cleanly exits the application.  Perhaps you're thinking of `os._exit()`, which is a nasty way to go?  Check `help(sys.exit)` for more.

Answer (score 0):

Few checkpoints

- Did you import sys?
- `if input_event_quit == 'Quit':` should be if `input_quit == 'Quit':`